# Bindings could not add observer to paths which are already observed by binding in another place

Tags: swift, macos, core-data

First — I even don't know how to describe this problem. I will start from the beginning.
I have a `NSTableView` with Managed Objects `Invoice` objects. `Invoice` has `client`, `date`... I can access to them by `invoice.client` in cells. OK. Works. When I double click on row, next widow with details of selected `Invoice` opens. It' done by binding `Double Click Argument` and `Double Click Target`. I'm passing `selectedObjects` to method, method loads `nib`, makes widndow and voila. In `NSViewController` subclass I have

```
@objc var invoice : Invoice? {
    didSet {print ("Set Invoice \(invoice?.description ?? "no invoice")")}
}
```

and it prints `Invoice`. It is set.

And now is a puzzle. If I try to bind ANY UI object (label to invoice.date, invoice.client.name etc..)
window does not pop after double-click and I got an error:

```
2019-08-31 22:13:45.252956+0200 fakturaVatParser[11444:12617343] [General] [<__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x60000004e180> addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:] is not supported. Key path: client
```

Not only `client`... every relationship and attribute of `Invoice`. The same paths which works perfectly in NSTabView cells.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is Invoice one invoice or an array of one invoice? `selectedObjects` is an array. The error says: "binding to (= observing) an array is not supported".

Comment: One moment ago I discovered that binding `Double Click Target` sends `__NSSingleObjectArrayI` to function `@objc func editInvoice(_ invoice: Invoice)` and that function pass this false `Invoice` aka `__NSSingleArrayObjectI` to view. Swift Strong type doesn't work? I try to find a way to get `Invoice` from `Invoice` aka `__NSSingleArrayObjectI`.

Comment: `__NSSingleArrayObjectI` is an array, `invoice` is a `[Invoice]`.

Comment: I know, but how it happened that array passed `Invoice`, not `[Invoice]` in function?

Comment: The double click binding calls `editInvoice` with argument `selectedObjects` which is an array. The arguments of the function must match the arguments of the binding.